# C# Form doesn't close

Tags: c#, winforms

In my Windows form the application doesn't exit even though I execute `this.Close();`

```
private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

If I try disposing it directly it just crashes.

In my main class I open an instance, which is what i'm trying to close. Before it didnt't want to close, it didn't open.

This is not my main class.

FIX: Replacing "show()" with "showDialog()" fixed it.

Comment: Any threads, any calls to ProcessMessages ? Anything else we might like to know?

Comment: My first guess: You have hooked up `FormClosing` and set `e.Cancel` to true.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046019/winforms-application-exit-vs-enviroment-exit-vs-form-close

Comment: there must be other code responsible for this, try to reproduce it in minimal code. Did you open more Forms? Did you override/hook FormClosing?

Comment: Read the `0xA3's` answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912836/c-sharp-why-does-form-close-not-close-the-form

Comment: @user3902017 - edit your question to clarify or it will get closed.

Comment: You should use Application.Exit() instead
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977924/how-to-properly-exit-a-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remarks from Form.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the Closing event and setting the Cancel
>   property of the CancelEventArgs passed as a parameter to your event
>   handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form of your
>   application, your application ends.
>
> The two conditions when a form is not disposed on Close is when (1) it
>   is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the
>   form is not visible; and (2) you have displayed the form using
>   ShowDialog. In these cases, you will need to call Dispose manually to
>   mark all of the form's controls for garbage collection. NoteNote
>
> When the Close method is called on a Form displayed as a modeless
>   window, you cannot call the Show method to make the form visible,
>   because the form's resources have already been released. To hide a
>   form and then make it visible, use the Control.Hide method. Caution
>   noteCaution
>
> Prior to the .NET Framework 2.0, the Form.Closed and Form.Closing
>   events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to
>   exit your application. If you have validation code in either of these
>   events that must be executed, you should call the Form.Close method
>   for each open form individually before calling the Exit method.

This clearly states that the form should close and application should end **unless you do something else we cannot see in your example.**

Answer (score -1):

The `Close` method is a `Form`'s method, it closes the Form, this closes the `Application` instead :

```
// Close everything down.
Application.Exit();
```

As you can see the [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application(v=vs.110).aspx) Class doesn't have a Close method, it has an Exit method instead, the `this.Close()` closes the concerned Form, but keeps the application running.

Comment: Op's title says Form doesn't close. Why would that happen? `Close` should close the form unless you set `e.Cancel` in `FormClosing` handler

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : he actually says : `... the application doesn't exit even though I execute this.Close();` he wants to exit the app, through closing the Form

Comment: Agreed, question is not clear. Title says one and content say another

Comment: Closing the MainForm should automatically terminate the process.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You're right. I downvoted this answer and later removed it. Because, we don't know whether it is the MainForm.

Comment: I'm willing to assume that exitButton_Click is a menu item on the MainForm. Something else is at play, the OP should clarify.

Comment: @HenkHolterman : it is not mentioned that it s about the Main Form, the OP seems to want to exit the app

Comment: Wait, Even though it is the MainForm, `Application.Exit` will not force the foreground threads to exit which will result in keeping the process alive. So technically this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that's a special case, the OP wants simply to close his app, I gave him a correction to what he tried, according to MSDN :

`Exit() : Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.`