# Creating a Window object and then calling it in an other Window class in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Why this first code works

```
MessageBox.Show("No Applicants\nFirst Add applicants with dataentryaccount");
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.Show();
this.Close();
```

But this second code doesn't show the mw window

```
    MessageBox.Show("No Applicants\nFirst Add applicants with dataentryaccount");
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
this.Close();
mw.Show();
```

Although when debugged Line by Line all these lines are executed.

Comment: because you are closing the `main` program window before you show next window

Comment: But When debugged Line by line,
the lines do execute?

How will you justify that

Comment: It has to exit the current procedure which is called..

Comment: I am still not getting it.

Afterall it is executing

Comment: Honestly - How aren't you getting an `ObjectDisposedException` in both examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventHandler or procedure` of the current execution block has some more code to execute.
You have not called `return` to stop the execution of the current procedure.

`Close()` is just another function which will not delete the form immediately. So it continues the execution of the current code.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3912874/1127849) answer for more details.

Comment: Hmmm, So you mean that the new window would be created, But because of it having no more reference it will eventually be disposed by the garbage collector